# Razor mediator implementation in Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, razor-mediator

I am trying to implement the Razor mediator in SDL Tridion 2011 Sp1.

Can any one suggest some useful links.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- In Alexander Klock's blog (The creator of the extension), you can
  find some useful posts under the mediator tag:

http://codedweapon.com/tag/mediator/

- Google Code Project page:

http://code.google.com/p/razor-mediator-4-tridion/

- Tridion world entry:

http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/razormediator.aspx

- Other blog posts:

http://www.curlette.com/?p=672

http://blog.building-blocks.com/razor-templating-sdl-tridion-2011

But I´m quite sure you could have found all these with a quick google search ;)

Answer (score 4):

you can find many details in below link

http://code.google.com/p/razor-mediator-4-tridion/